# Frequency of Address changes in number of days SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

Hi I'm trying to find out how frequently a business would change their address. I've got two tables one with trading address and the other with office address. The complicated part is one id will have several sequence numbers. I need to find out the difference between one address's create date and another address create date.

`Trading address table`

| ID | Create_date | Seq_no | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2002-03-23 | 1 | 20 bottle way |
| 1 | 2002-05-23 | 2 | 12 sunset blvd |
| 2 | 2003-01-14 | 1 | 76 moonrise ct |

`Office address table`

| ID | Create_date | Seq_no | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2004-02-13 | 1 | 12 paper st |
| 2 | 2005-03-01 | 1 | 30 pencil way |
| 2 | 2005-04-01 | 2 | 25 mouse rd |
| 2 | 2005-08-01 | 3 | 89 glass cct |

My result set will be

| Difference | NumberOfID's |
| --- | --- |
| 30 days | 1 |
| 60 days | 1 |
| 120 days | 1 |
| Other | 2 |

Comment: Can you provide a description how are results are formed row by row?

Comment: Yep, sure Basically result set will be the union of both the tables and finding the date difference between create_dates based on seq_no

If you notice the the first row in result set came from the trading address table. It is the create date difference of ID 1. The second row is from office address table for id 2.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it. Steps are

1. I did an union and created a separate column to find out actual
   sequence no for the union set.
2. Used LEAD function to create a separate column of to bring up the date.
3. Date difference to find out the actual difference between id's
4. Case statement to categorize the days and counting the id's

   ```
   WITH BASE AS (

   SELECT ID,SEQ_NO,CREATE_DATE
   FROM TradingAddress
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ID,SEQ_NO,CREATE_DATE
   FROM OfficeAddress
   ),

   WORKINGS AS  (
                 SELECT ID,CREATE_DATE,
                 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CREATE_DATE ASC) AS SNO,
                 LEAD(CREATE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CREATE_DATE) AS REF_DATE,
                 DATEDIFF(DAY,CREATE_DATE,LEAD(CREATE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CREATE_DATE)) AS DATE_DIFFERENCE
                 FROM BASE
                ),

   WORKINGS_2 AS (
            SELECT *,
            CASE WHEN DATE_DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 1 AND 30 THEN '1-30 DAYS'
            WHEN DATE_DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN '31-60 DAYS'
            WHEN DATE_DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN '61-90 DAYS'
            WHEN DATE_DIFFERENCE BETWEEN 91 AND 120 THEN '91-120 DAYS'ELSE 'MORE THAN 120 DAYS' 
            END AS DIFFERENCE_DAYS
            FROM WORKINGS
            WHERE REF_DATE IS NOT NULL
         )

               SELECT DIFFERENCE_DAYS,COUNT(DIFFERENCE_DAYS) AS NUMBEROFIDS
               FROM WORKINGS_2
               GROUP BY DIFFERENCE_DAYS
   ```

Comment: An where do you use `seq_no`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in this way

`SELECT DATEDIFF(day,t1.create_date,t2.create_date) AS 'yourdats', Count (*)  as ids   FROM test1 t1 join test2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,t1.create_date,t2.create_date)`